# Grunt: .git/index.lock File exists error when running grunt-gh-pages

Tags: git, gruntjs, github-pages

When running `grunt-gh-pages` with `grunt`, it fails in the middle of the task with the error

> Warning: fatal: Unable to create
>   '/home/richard/src/tumblr-argument-generator/.git/index.lock': File
>   exists.
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
>   git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
>   process is running and remove the file manually to continue.  Use
>   --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I tried deleting the file with `sudo rm -f ./.git/index.lock` (error persisted), I tried deleting the `gh-pages` branch + deleting `index.lock` and still got the error, I tried deleting my files + pruning the `gh-pages` branch on Github + and re-downloading a fresh copy from Github (same error).

How can I get `grunt-gh-pages` to run correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The clue was that `.grunt` folder contained a `grunt-gh-pages` subfolder.

Deleting the `.grunt` folder fixed all the `.git/index.lock': File exists` errors!